# why use neo4j swagger instead of expressjs routes / controllers and the neo4j npm package?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, swagger

I really want to use the right toolset to correctly build out a REST api that consumes neo4j, and I began doing that with the neo4j package, and the expressjs routes & controllers pattern. It works just like you would expect when building a mean stack application.

Then, I started seeing stuff about neo4j swagger for building rest api's around neo4j, but it seems like its doing the same stuff. what is it for and should it be used to do what i'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use what you said

Swagger is mean to be for designing clear API's which are also consumed by others

Comment: so, does that mean that a bad API cannot be written using swagger? isn't the clarity of your API basically limited to the quality of coding the developer is capable of designing and writing?

Comment: quality of the API is not so much related to the code but the API design and the contracts it adheres to